# jquery accessing data-attrs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using bootstrap modal for destroying task objects. When I click on a given task on the index page the modal window pops up and the destroy link of that task gets loaded via data attr, so modal will know which task should be destroyed when user clicks on `#delete-task-submit` button.

The code works as it is, but I'd like to use `data-behavior="delete-task-submit"` instead of `#delete-task-submit` to be clear that this has nothing to do with styling and it's only there for the js call.

What's the right way to do it? I'm asking this because `#delete-task-submit` is used in the first js call for finding/setting `data-task-destroy-link` and don't know how else I can find that data attribute without adding id/extra class there.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete-task-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" style="text-align:left">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Task</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Are you sure?</h4>
        <p> </p>  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="deletetaskclose">Close</button>
        <a href="#" id="delete-task-submit" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-task-destroy-link >Delete Task</a>
          <!-- DESTROY LINK GETS INSERTED HERE -->      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).on('click', '[data-behavior="open-delete-task-modal"]', function (event) {
  var taskDeleteLink = $(this).data("task-delete-link");
  $('#delete-task-submit').data("task-destroy-link", taskDeleteLink);
});

$(document).on('click', '#delete-task-submit', function (event) {
  var href = $(this).data("task-destroy-link");
  $.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: href,
    dataType: "script"
  });
});
```

Comment: Use `$('[data-task-destroy-link]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm asking this because `#delete-task-submit` is **used in the first js call for finding**/setting data-task-destroy-link and don't know how else I can find that data attribute without adding id/extra class there.

Replace `$('#delete-task-submit')` with `$('[data-behavior="delete-task-submit"]')` selector in that part of your code and add `data-behavior="delete-task-submit"` attribute to your link.

```
<a href="#" id="" data-behavior="delete-task-submit" class="...">Delete Task</a>
```